# Is there a way to use a style setter for properties of properties?

Tags: wpf, xaml, controls, styles

**Edit:** *In the original question i made some wrong assumptions about how setters work so i modified it to hopefully be more accurate and useful.*

I have tried to make some menu items more interesting by having the icons appear half-transparent if the mouse is not over the item. If the mouse enters, the icon should be animated to become completely visible.
The animations work, `Storyboard.TargetProperty` allows direct access to the icon's opacity property:

```
<Style x:Key="MenuItemMouseOverStyle" TargetType="MenuItem">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Icon.Opacity">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.5"/>
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="1"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Icon.Opacity">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="0.5"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

If i try to use a setter for the initial icon-opacity the code won't compile:

```
<Setter Property="Icon.Opacity" Value="0.5"/>
```

---

**Edit:**
*Setters do not work the way i tried to use them, you cannot access the properties of properties (see answers)
The only thing you can do is specify a target class if the target type of the style has not been set, the following styles should be equivalent:*

```
<Style x:Key="Style1" TargetType="Image">
    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5"/>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="Style2">
    <Setter Property="Image.Opacity" Value="0.5"/>
</Style>
```

---

So my question is if there is a way to make this somehow work with a setter.

(My current work-around is a single-keyframe storyboard that is triggered with the `Loaded` event which works quite well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can access a Property of a Property like that so the casting itself isn't the problem. Even if Icon was of Type Image that still wouldn't work. You can try with Backgrounds Opacity for a Grid for example. Background is a Dependency Property for Grid and Opacity is a Dependency Property for Brush but the following line won't work

```
<Grid Background.Opacity="0.8"/>
```

You'll get an error saying

> The attachable property 'Opacity' was
>   not found in type 'Background'.

You would have to set this in the Background itself like this

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Opacity="0.8"/>
    </Grid.Background>
</Grid>
```

So what this means as when you do something like this

```
<Grid TextBlock.Foreground="Red">
    <TextBlock Text="Test"/>
</Grid>
```

you're actually using the Attached Property Foreground for TextBlock.

Image doesn't have an Attached Property called Opacity so you can't do this either

```
<MenuItem Image.Opacity="0.8" />
```

Another workaround besides the one you're already doing is to use something like this (top-most MenuItem or wherever you want to use it).

```
<MenuItem x:Name="topMenuItem"
          ...>
    <MenuItem.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Image">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5"/>
        </Style>
    </MenuItem.Resources>
    <!-- ... -->
</MenuItem>
```

Comment: Your proposed solution works but is even more of a pain than the single keyframe workaround because the setter should be in the same style definition since it belongs to the animations. Well, i did not expect any nice solution because the whole setter and trigger business is a bit restrictive (e.g. EventTriggers only work with storyboards and not simple setters)
Thanks anyway.

Comment: @H.B.: Yes I agree, the solution you're already using is better so just keep using it :) If Resources was a DP you could have added that to your MenuItem Style but since it's not that's a no go

Comment: I do not quite understand what you mean, why should the resources be a DP?
Embedding the image style in the Style.Resources seems to work...

Comment: @H.B.: You're right! Style.Resources will work. I meant that you can't put Resources in a setter but as you said, Style.Resources will work. Thanks for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 2):

So after reading Meleak's answer and finding out that you can have a style within a style via resources what probably comes closest to doing this with a setter is an embedded style to access the icon's opacity. Here i assume the icon to be an image so i use that as the target type, the complete style hence looks like this:

```
<Style x:Key="MenuItemMouseOverStyle" TargetType="MenuItem">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Image">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5"/>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Icon.Opacity">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.5"/>
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="1"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Icon.Opacity">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="0.5"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The only problem with this is that it does not actually set the `Icon.Opacity` but the opacity of all images that may occur within the MenuItem.