# Using a DataTrigger to set the properties of a ScaleTransform

Tags: wpf, xaml

A failed XAML attempt here - I'm obviously doing something stupid with the `Style`/`Setter` syntax. I just want to flip an element based on some bindings by setting the `ScaleX` and `ScaleY` properties of a `ScaleTransform` from a `DataTrigger`. `Setter.Property` obviously doesn't support a property path, but how can I get round this? I can't set the whole `RenderTransform` property because `ScaleX` and `ScaleY` are independent. Any ideas?

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
   <StackPanel>
      <TextBlock FontSize="50" RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5">
         <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style>
               <Style.Triggers>
                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=FlipX}" Value="True">
                     <Setter Property="RenderTransform.ScaleX" Value="-1"/>
                  </DataTrigger>
                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=FlipY}" Value="True">
                     <Setter Property="RenderTransform.ScaleY" Value="-1"/>
                  </DataTrigger>
               </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
         </TextBlock.Style>
         <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
          <ScaleTransform/>
         </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
      Hello World
      </TextBlock>
      <CheckBox Name="FlipX">Flip x</CheckBox>
      <CheckBox Name="FlipY">Flip y</CheckBox>
   </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

Comment: Set the RenderTransform to a StaticResource transform with the ScaleX and ScaleY already set to -1 in your trigger.

Comment: @Will But ScaleX and ScaleY are independent - there's a checkbox to control each of them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to use a style setter for properties of properties?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577131/is-there-a-way-to-use-a-style-setter-for-properties-of-properties)

Comment: @H.B. Sort of, but the solution there is to apply a Style to the child property. I can't do that.

Comment: @TimRogers: aw, heck.  Its a bit more complex, then.  Can't answer off the top of my head.

Comment: @TimRogers: That does not change the fact that it is the same question.

Comment: @H.B. I've changed the question title. Happy?

Comment: @TimRogers: lol, making something more specific than needed is not a solution to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setters work on elements, and `Transform` doesn't derive from `UIElement`, so I don't think you're going to be able to do this using a style.

I'd fix this in the view model:  implement boolean `FlipX` and `FlipY` properties, and expose `ScaleX` and `ScaleY` properties that the `ScaleTransform` can bind to.

Comment: This is probably simpler than messing around with XAML. I used a similar solution in the end and wrote a multivalue converter that produces a Transform as the end result.

Answer (score 8):

You could use:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=FlipX}" Value="True" />
            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=FlipY}" Value="True" />
         </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
         <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
             <Setter.Value>
                 <ScaleTransform ScaleX="-1" ScaleY="-1" />
             </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
    </MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=FlipX}" Value="True" />
            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=FlipY}" Value="False" />
         </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
         <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
             <Setter.Value>
                 <ScaleTransform ScaleX="-1" ScaleY="1" />
             </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
    </MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=FlipX}" Value="False" />
            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=FlipY}" Value="True" />
         </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
         <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
             <Setter.Value>
                 <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="-1" />
             </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
    </MultiDataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: I had the same idea but thought it to be way too redundant to actually use.

Answer (score 0):

- Either use animations, can be single frame & instant.
- Or encapsulate some of this structure in the Template of a ContentControl. Then you can name the transform and you can try targeting it with the [`Setter.TargetName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.setter.targetname.aspx).