# Accessing a Transform from a UserControl's Style

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

I've got some XAML for a UserControl that looks roughly like this:

```
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.RenderTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
    </UserControl.RenderTransform>
    <UserControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="UserControl">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="..." Value="...">
                    <Setter Property="RenderTransform.ScaleX" Value="0.5" />
                    <Setter Property="RenderTransform.ScaleY" Value="0.5" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Style>
</UserControl>
```

But when I compile, I get the error:

> Cannot resolve the Style Property 'ScaleX'. Verify that the owning
>   type is the Style's TargetType, or use Class.Property syntax to
>   specify the Property.

I've tried all sorts of permutations of the Property but I can't find one that actually works. In other cases, I'll just name the ScaleTransform and reference that with TargetName. But you can't use TargetName in a Style Setter.

I guess my alternative is something like this:

```
<Setter Property="RenderTransform">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.5" ScaleY="0.5" />
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

But that seems a little heavy-handed.

I'm sure I'm just missing something. But I could really use some help here.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577131/is-there-a-way-to-use-a-style-setter-for-properties-of-properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setters do not allow property paths. If your scenario allows it switch out the whole transform with a new one. Alternatively you can use a single frame animation, which is even heavier.

Comment: Thanks H.B. - I was afraid that was the case. But I tend to assume I'm doing something wrong :)

Comment: @Tim: Sadly there are quite a few limitations on styling, another one for example is that one cannot apply multiple styles to one control, that would be rather useful in some cases.