# Setting a sub property in a style

Tags: wpf, styles

How do I set a sub-property in a style?

I want to set an InkPresenter DefaultDrawingAttribute.Color property.

This does not work:

```
<Style x:Key="InkCanvasStyle" TargetType="{x:Type InkCanvas}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Source={x:Static Application.Current}, Path=BackColour}" />
    <Setter Property="DefaultDrawingAttributes.Color" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Pen" />
</Style>
```

**Edit**

Ended up being fairly simple:

```
    <Setter Property="DefaultDrawingAttributes">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DrawingAttributes Color="White" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to use a style setter for properties of properties?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577131/is-there-a-way-to-use-a-style-setter-for-properties-of-properties)

Comment: Had a look at the question and answer you mentioned but can't see how to do what I need to do there.

Comment: That is unfortunate, how about using a `Loaded` event to make changes then?

Comment: 1. You cannot bind anything in the attrbutes object 2. You cannot style the attributes object 3. In the first case you try to apply a style to the property which should contain a color which does not make any sense at all. 4. You can just create the whole attributes from scratch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using property-element syntax?

```
        <Style x:Key="InkCanvasStyle" TargetType="{x:Type InkCanvas}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Source={x:Static Application.Current}, Path=BackColour}" />
            <Setter Property="DefaultDrawingAttributes">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DrawingAttributes Color="White" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Pen" />
        </Style>
```

This is doing more than just setting the color attribute, it is creating a new `DrawingAttributes` object and then setting the `Color` attribute.

Comment: Only problem I have now is it says I can't bind to the Color property as it is not a Dependency Property on a Dependency Object. Any ideas?

Comment: As H.B. noted above, you won't be able to bind and there is not much you can do to work around this. However, DefaultDrawingAttributes is a DP so that could be bound to instead.

Answer (score 1):

Even if [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577131/is-there-a-way-to-use-a-style-setter-for-properties-of-properties) does not cover this there surely is a question which covers this case too. As this is an attribute collection you probably will not run into trouble for creating the whole object (as i noted in the comment):

```
<Setter Property="DefaultDrawingAttributes">
    <Setter.Value>
        <DrawingAttributes Color="White"/>
    <Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Alternativly you can always modify the object after it `Loaded` using an `EventSetter` (as i noted in the comment).