# Why can I not access some properties on WPF controls?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to apply styles to a control in WPF. And have noticed that some properties available in code behind arent available in XAML?

Why is this?

And can you help me with the following example:

```
<Style TargetType="RichTextBox">
        <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="WhiteSmoke"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#515151"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Document.PageWidth" Value="300"></Setter>
    </Style>
```

When trying to apply the PageWidth to the Document of the control, I get an exception that it is not accessible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set styles for the Dependency Property alone

Answer (score 1):

`Setter.Property` is *not* a path, you cannot use it to set "properties of properties".

Comment: can you explain a bit more with and article or example? Sorry don't know wpf.

Comment: @shenku: In a related [question of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577131/is-there-a-way-to-use-a-style-setter-for-properties-of-properties) most of it should be covered. Also read the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.setter.property.aspx).